# Как сделать резиновую разметку так, чтобы не вмещающиеся элементы переносились на следующую строку?

Tags: android

можно ли сделать резиновую разметку в приложении, так чтобы добавляемые из кода элементы дополнялись слева на право, с переходом на следующую строку?

макет:

button1  button2  button3  button4  button5

button6  button7  button8  button9  button10

button11 button12

Comment: Да, можно. Используйте GridLayout

Comment: Используйте FlowLayout

Answer (score 8, accepted):

То, что вам надо, называется FlowLayout

Воспользуйтесь одной из библиотек: [FlowLayout](https://github.com/blazsolar/FlowLayout) или [android-flowlayout](https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout)

В случае первой либы в разметку добавьте `FlowLayout`, а в него нужное кол-во ваших виджетов, кои надо переносить на другую строку, если они не вмещаются

```
<com.wefika.flowlayout.FlowLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="start|top">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum" />

    <!-- тут ещё много вьюх -->

</com.wefika.flowlayout.FlowLayout>
```

Получится примерно так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Есть контейнер и из гугловских библиотек поддержки [FlexboxLayout](https://habrahabr.ru/company/speakasap/blog/300908/) - во много более функциональный виджет, чем `FlowLayout`

Comment: Есть контейнер из гугловских библиотек поддержки [`FlexboxLayout`](https://habrahabr.ru/company/speakasap/blog/300908/) - во много более функциональный виджет, чем `FlowLayout`

Comment: @pavlofff, добавил это в ответ)