# Сложное взаимодействие элементов в RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

Пытаюсь найти решение чтоб элементы в RelativeLayout прилипали к левому краю (они динамически добавляются и имеют разное расположение по оси Y) , но если на пути к левому краю есть другой View тогда к нему. Все вью добавляютсся програмным способом. Есть ли вариан сделать это с помощью лейаутов или надо програмно это делать?

[image: [Хочу чтоб вот так было. Имейте ввиду что это динамически добавленные элементы]

Comment: Т.е. просто вьюхи расположенные горизонтально один за другим? Для этого LinearLayout есть

Comment: Не подойдет LinearLayout, потому что если на пути к левому краю нету  елементов, он должен пристать к краю парента

Comment: Вы всё ещё описываете LinearLayout. Наверное вы имеете в виду расположение элементов ещё и вертикально? Тогда добавьте подробностей в вопрос. Ну и картинку какую-нить неплохо увидеть. И если задача реально такова, то такое можно только программно сделать.

Comment: Надеюсь теперь понятнее?

Comment: Немного понятнее. Если вот это не подойдёт, то придётся самостоятельно, наверное, реализовывать
http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/544055/17609

Answer (score 0):

Надо новые вьюшки добавлять с атрибутом `android:layout_below`, типа:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_below="@id/prevView" <!-- идентификатор предыдущей вьюшки -->
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="Blah-blah" />
```

Это гарантирует, что вьюшка (в данном случае `TextView`) будет всегда на новой строке и выровнена с левой стороны

Comment: я вьюшки динамически добавляю, соответственно не могу знать их id в лейауте

Comment: Это типичное заблуждение - при динамическом создании надо присваивать айдишки вручную, так что все ок. Я уже делал это мильон лет назад - [тынц](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6790623/programmatic-views-how-to-set-unique-ids)