# Функция из последнего API

Tags: android

Ребята, помогите найти.

Препод сказал, что в последней api внесли функцию,
которая меряет экран пользователя и в зависимости от его размера подгоняет вью элементы.
Я что то не могу в документации про это найти.

Eще преподаватель сказал, что есть уже готовые библиотеки для таких вычислений, если кто знает, поделитесь ссылкой плиз.

Comment: Наверное имеется в виду последнее из упомянутых в этом ответе: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/544033/17609, а именно FlexboxLayout

Comment: а мне чего то кажется что речь идет о https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Очень "мутное" описание, расскажите вашему преподу о важности для программиста внятного ТЗ.

Видимо речь идет о [этой функции](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html?hl=ru#screen-zoom), которой не придумали громкого названия. Позволяет увеличивать\уменьшать элементы на экране для людей со слабым\орлинным зрением.